# Show a set of vectors is a basis for the space of linear transforms

Tags: vector-spaces

Define:

f: R^n->R

by:

f(x)=ei*x, where ei is the i-th basis vector in R^n

{f1,f2,..,fn}

Suppose:

c1f1+c2f2+...+cnfn=0

Now

I know that if I feed the fs ei, i will be left with

Ci=0. This is the only proof I can come up with. But I struggle with the question, how can I assume, that by the above, no other combination exists that would give zero?

The part that bothers me, suppose we are in R^2 and we feed it (1,-1)^t

we have

c1-c2=0. Doesn't this imply, that c1 may be equal to c2...

I thank you for your help in advance, I'm an amateur mathematician, with noone but the good stackexchange to ask :)

Edit:

I'll include the span for good meassure:

T:
T= Sum of (cifi(x))

=> ci=T(ei)

T(x)=T(Sum of(xiei))

T(x)=Sum of(xi)T(ei)

T(x)= Sum of (cifi(x))

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your post is incorrect. The concern is misplaced, however: nothing is contradictory.

For instance, given the general linear combination $0=c_1f_1+c_2f_2$, we can determine the constants by producing two linearly-independent equations, say, by evaluating the right side at various points.

If we choose $(1,-1)$ to be our first point, as you have done, then we get $0=c_1-c_2$. But this is not enough: we need a second point.

A natural choice would be $(1,1)$ since this vector is orthogonal to $(1,-1)$, but you could choose anything (except for a scalar multiple of $(1,-1)$ of course!). In this case we find that $0=c_1+c_2$ as well.

But now we have the system of equations

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
c_1-c_2=0 \\
c_1+c_2=0
\end{array} \right. $$

which, if you solve it, does indeed give $c_1=0$ and $c_2=0$.

We can interpret this from the perspective of your proof: by linearity we know that the first equation is $E_1-E_2$ (where $E_i$ is the equation $c_i=0$ that you get from evaluating at the vector $e_i$) and the second one is $E_1+E_2$, then the system of equations is

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} E_1\\E_2 \end{bmatrix}
\qquad\qquad
\text{or}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} c_1\\c_2 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Notice that the points you chose are precisely the rows of the matrix. This phenomenon is general, so left-multiplying by the matrix's inverse is one way to see that the result will not depend on the points you choose. (Assuming, as before, that you choose points that result in linearly-independent equations, which is equivalent to saying that the matrix must be invertible.)